# Why Vary Header is different for CURL --head and Chrome's F12 Dev Tools

Tags: browsers, http-headers, user-agent

I am trying to study the HTTP response headers in popular websites. The objective is that I can cross-check with my website and adapt good things.

I tried to find how `Vary` header looks in the response for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Based on the `Curl --head` and `wget -S` commands, the vary header is this

```
Vary: Fastly-SSL
```

However, when I examined the response via Chrome's F12 (dev tools), the response was this

```
vary: Accept-Encoding,Fastly-SSL
```

Seems the server responds with different vary headers for different user-agents/request-headers. But why exactly this is done? Why not include Accept-Encoding for all requests? Is there some optimization which I am missing?

Comment: A late comment, but since I'm troubleshooting this at work, I've noticed there is some waf rule that distinguishes users and responds with the vary header. So far I'm speculating that it's because they want to serve browser users with gzip resources whereas curl response they ignore.